# Excel Macro to select data and blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks in advance for any help.
I have a spreadsheet that has data in Columns A to AD and the rows of data differ every time I use the spreadsheet.
I need to be able to do 2 things in a Macro

1. Select Columns A to AD with 50 blank rows after the last row
   that has data.  For example, if data goes to row 12, I need to
   select A1:AD62.  I then need to add all borders to the cell range
2. I then need to select the blank rows that were bordered along with
   Columns AC:AD up to the blank rows that were added.  For example i
   would need to select A13:AB62 and AC1:AD62.  I would then format
   those cells to remove the Locked checkbox in the protection
   formatting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post what you have for the macro so far?

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy of a rejigged Macro Recorder (it's your friend!) output and assuming it's on the active sheet and not on some other one:

```
Sub formatAndUnlock()

Dim lCount As Long

    With ActiveSheet

        lCount = .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A1:AD" & lCount + 50)
            .Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThin
            .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlThin
        End With

        .Range("A" & lCount +1 & ":AB" & lCount + 50).Locked = False
        .Range("AC1:AD" & lCount + 50).Locked = False

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It works great, but the last row that has data is showing unlocked.  So using my example, rows 1 to 11 are locked, but row 12 (that still has data) shows unlocked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @user2962359 Edited to include a +1, try the above.